# Error al pulsar un boton en selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy haciendo pruebas con selenium en esta [página](https://www.justwatch.com/es/proveedor/hbo-max/peliculas).
Al entrar por primera vez a la página se deben de marcar la opciones de privacidad pero no se porque no me funciona ninguno de los métodos que había usado anteriormente, quiero pulsar el botón de guardar configuración.

```
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-save-button" class="sc-gsDKAQ eaUldE" style="margin: 0px 6px;">Guardar configuración</button>
```

Lo he intentado localizando el botón mediante texto, clase y usando el `XPath`, pero la ejecución se detiene al terminar el tiempo de espera.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-gsDKAQ eaUldE'.replace(' ', '.'))))\
.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]//div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button[1]')))\
.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Guardar configuración')))\
.click()
```

Agradecería se alguien pudiera guiarme en el problema. Gracias.

Comment: De casualidad estás usando el modo **headless**? A veces es problemas. También puede ser que el elemento que cliqueas no sea el correcto. Si no encuentras solución, es probable que el diálogo solo se muestre si no existe una cookie. Podrías crearla manualmente, recargar y ya no aparecería más.

Comment: Estás dando por supuesto que el elemento existe al inicio. Seguramente sea un elemento que se crea al vuelo y tengas que esperar a que aparezca en el DOM antes de comprobar si es _clickable_.

Comment: @Mateo no estaba usando el modo headless. Voy a investigar lo de la cookie, sabrias decirme si el elemento no es el correcto? Gracias

Comment: @ChemaCortes acabo de fijarme en que el botón se encuentra en un árbol de Shadow DOM. Creo que el problema esta relacionado con eso, sabrías como gestionarlo. Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: No lo sé. Acabo de entrar y no me aparece ningún aviso en esa página. Quizá si compartes una captura podamos ayudarte

Comment: El _shadow DOM_ o _virtual DOM_ son optimizaciones del código javascript. Selenium trabaja con los eventos del navegador del DOM visible. No queda otra que esperar a que aparezca el botón. Míra el apartado de la documentación relativo a las [esperas](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). Igual es cuestión de esperar más segundos.

Comment: Otra posibilidad es que ese botón nunca tenga el foco, por lo que no tendrá el estado de clickable. Búscalo como un elemento.